# Unix Script Search pattern and append next line to that appropraite

Tags: shell, unix

Source File

```
:20:abcd  
:28D:a   
:50H:/1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
:30:020108
```

Output should be

```
:20:abcd  
:28D:a  
:50H:/1 2 3 4 5   
:30:020108
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @DanielGibbs The question (the statement of the problem) is in the title,  further the OP shows her/his input as well as the requested output in the body of the question.  The answer of John is perfectly on point... What else? +1 to the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{printf "%s",$0;next;} /^:/{printf "\n%s",$0;next} {printf " %s",$0;} END{print""}' file
:20:abcd
:28D:a 
:50H:/1 2 3 4 5
:30:020108
```

Here is another that uses fewer commands but has slightly more subtle logic:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",(/^:/ && NR>1)?"\n":sp,$0;sp=" "} END{print""}' file
:20:abcd
:28D:a 
:50H:/1 2 3 4 5
:30:020108
```

#### Explanation

Both solutions work similarly: every time a line is encountered that starts with a colon, it is printed out on a new line.  Every line that doesn't is appended to the previous line.

Normally, when a program prints a line, a newline character is appended to the end of the line.  In this program, we don't know whether the current line needs a newline character until we have had a look at the next line.  So, each line is printed without a trailing newline.  At the beginning of the next line, we decide to print either a newline character (to start a new line) or a space (in order to append the new line to the last line).

Let's look at the second solution above in more detail:

- `printf "%s%s",(/^:/ && NR>1)?"\n":sp,$0

  This prints out (a) a newline character or the variable `sp`, followed by (b) the current line.  The decision to print the newline or `sp` is made by this ternary statement:

  ```
  (/^:/ && NR>1)?"\n":sp
  ```

  If the line starts with a colon, `/^:/`, *and* this is not the first line, `NR>1`, then the quantity in parentheses evaluates to true and the newline character, `\n` is selected.  Otherwise the variable `sp` is selected.

  At the start of the program, `sp` has the usual `awk` default value of an empty string.
- `sp=" "`

  After the first line is printed, `sp` is assigned to a space.  It will retain this value for the rest of the program.
- `END{print""}`

  At the end of the program, one more newline character is printed to complete the last line.

Comment: @user3256262 OK.  I have added an explanation.